# Automate manual color selection for `geom_tile`s

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this type of data:

```
target_seq <- structure(list(Line = c("130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", 
                                      "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142"), 
                             Actor = c("R", "R", "R", "R", "B", "R", "B", "B", "B", "M", "M", "M", "M"), 
                             Act_cat = c("ver", "SpeechRec", "ges", "ges", "gaze", "ges", 
                                         "gaze", "gaze", "gaze", "gaze", "gaze", "gaze", "gaze"), 
                             Activity = c("dort drüben könnt ihr sehen wer damals auf der sparrenburg gewohnt hat", 
                                          "schwert", "D-onset", "D-peak", "~", "D-retract", "@tum", 
                                          "~", "@tum", "~", "@tum", "~", "@tum"), 
                             Starttime_ms = c(48825, 48865, 49220, 50080, 50730, 50900, 51009, 51191, 51270, 51486, 51809, 52251, 52333), 
                             Endtime_ms = c(53035, 49865, 50080, 50900, 51009, 52220, 51191, 51270, 53474, 51808, 52250, 52332, 53226), 
                             Duration = c(4210, 1000, 860, 820,279, 1320, 182, 79, 2204, 322, 441, 81, 893), 
                             File = c("VP_4_004", "VP_4_004", "VP_4_004", "VP_4_004", "VP_4_004", "VP_4_004", 
                                      "VP_4_004", "VP_4_004", "VP_4_004", "VP_4_004", "VP_4_004", 
                                      "VP_4_004", "VP_4_004"), 
                             Action = c("R_ver", "R_SpeechRec", "R_ges", "R_ges", "B_gaze", "R_ges", "B_gaze", "B_gaze", 
                                          "B_gaze", "M_gaze", "M_gaze", "M_gaze", "M_gaze")), 
                        class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

I want to plot all `Activity` values as `geom_tiles`. I can do that with this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(target_seq,
       aes(y = Action)) +
  # draw tiles for each `Activity` (width of tiles determined by `Duration`):
  geom_tile(aes(x = Starttime_ms + Duration/2, width = Duration, height = 0.3, fill = Actor), color = "white") +
  # print text of `Activity`s:
  geom_text(aes(x = Starttime_ms, label = Activity), hjust = 0, size = 3.5) +
  # define labels for x- and y-axis and plot tile:
  labs(
    # x- axis label:
    x = "Activity duration",
    # y-axis label:
    y = "Actors and activity type",
    # plot title:
    title = paste0("Activities during robot's utterance\nFile: ", 
                   target_seq$File, 
                   " [", 
                   min(target_seq$Line, na.rm = TRUE),
                   " - ",
                   max(target_seq$Line, na.rm = TRUE),
                   "]"))
```

which gives:
[image]

I'd like to **choose my own colors** for the tiles. To complicate matters a little, this `target_seq` is just one out of many and **the number and identity of the `Actors` changes** from `File` to `File`. How can I automate a manual selection of colors for the `geom_tile`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vector storing the name of the "Actor" and their corresponding colours. Then use the vector in `scale_fill_manual(values = vector)`.

Here my vector is `tile_fill`, which fills actor B with blue, R with red and M with green (the Actor names comes from your `target_seq`).

```
library(ggplot2)

tile_fill <- c("A" = "orange", "B" = "blue", "C" = "purple" ,"R" = "red", "M" = "green")

ggplot(target_seq,
       aes(y = Action)) +
  # draw tiles for each `Activity` (width of tiles determined by `Duration`):
  geom_tile(aes(x = Starttime_ms + Duration/2, width = Duration, height = 0.3, fill = Actor), color = "white") +
  # print text of `Activity`s:
  geom_text(aes(x = Starttime_ms, label = Activity), hjust = 0, size = 3.5) +
  # define labels for x- and y-axis and plot tile:
  labs(
    # x- axis label:
    x = "Activity duration",
    # y-axis label:
    y = "Actors and activity type",
    # plot title:
    title = paste0("Activities during robot's utterance\nFile: ", 
                   target_seq$File, 
                   " [", 
                   min(target_seq$Line, na.rm = TRUE),
                   " - ",
                   max(target_seq$Line, na.rm = TRUE),
                   "]")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = tile_fill[names(tile_fill) %in% target_seq$Actor])
```

[image: geom_tile_fill]

Comment: Okay, but how does this address the issue of there being different numbers and identities of `Actors` in different files?

Comment: So what you want is a "master" colour database that includes all colour combinations for all Actors, even some Actors are not in the current dataframe? I have edited my code that you can use your current dataframe to set the names of the vector. So what you need to do is to choose your own colour, incorporate it into the vector before plotting. Is that what you want?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work...

Comment: What is not working? The idea or the code? For the code it runs perfectly fine on my side, so you may need to give more details.

Comment: For the data posted, yes. But, as noted, in the actual data there are more `File`s and more `Actors`. If I set up colors for all of them in advance and then subset on the unique values in the specific `File` filtered for plotting, there will be `NA` values in `tile_fill`- these it seems cannot be processed.

Comment: See my updated answer. Now the `tile_fill` contains Actors that are not in the current dataframe. In `scale_fill_manual`, you can subset the `tile_fill` to only include the ones that appeared in the current dataframe, therefore Actor A and C will not be displayed in the `ggplot`.